# How to save the filtered state of p:datatable after multiple page refresh?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to this website.  I am using Jsf and Primefaces.

Steps:-

- I apply filter to choose a row and click its Edit button.
- An Edit form is opened where I edit and save the changes.
- It    leads me to the datatable form with all the list rather than
  the    filtered list.

Problem/Requirement:-

- When I return on my datatable form,I want my datatable to be in the
  same filtered state.

  I have seen a similar problem here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9158 ,but that doesnt help me.
- Note:-My filter p:inputtext is not in the p:datatable. and I am using
  ViewScoped Bean  Is there any solution in jsf and primefaces.

  Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What solution? Url?  See also [ask]

Comment: See my first comment above. Reference to what you tried and didnot understand

Comment: You may either keep the filter status in the SessionScope or you may use some Cookie to store the filter status on client side and then apply it via JS

Comment: @Kukeltje,Thanks for the help.I have modified the question.Please check it.

Comment: @stg,Thanks for the reply,I can't use Session scope and can i dont know what to include ion js.

Comment: If the filter is outside the datatable, you most likely do the filtering yourself and your are then also responsible to reapply it when returning to the page.  But maybe the filteredValue attribute can help you

Comment: @Kukeltje,I have kept onkeyup="PF('datatable').filter()" on my filter p:inputtext,so Primefaces does the filtering and I am trying with the filteredValue attribute,but till now,no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,  I stored the filteredList attribute of p:datatable in the flash scope across multiple beans wherever needed and updated the filter p:inputtext from the bean method.
Thanks @Kukeltje and @stg for your help